# How to sign a REST api call

Tags: rest

I am trying to hit a REST endpoint that looks like the following

```
http://api.example.com/api.aspx?action=getShopCat&nick={nick}&sign={signature}
```

however the documentation for this is pretty terrible and I'm kind of at a loss on generating the signature

```
Encryption signature algorithm = base64(md5(md5(minute time stamp + key)));
key = 1b46af52a8dcaexample1be9d447bb2;
```

The most they have is a demo in C#

```
public static int ConvertDateMinTimeDouble(System.DateTime time)
      {
          System.DateTime startTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
          return (int)(time - startTime).TotalMinutes;
      }
```

Am I able to do this all in a program like postman? I'm not exactly sure where to start here

Comment: Curious that they're using `ToLocalTime` - why aren't they using UTC?

Comment: @Dai I really wish I could say the documentation is all in Chinese and poorly written:(

Comment: @Dai it does not matter if using local time or UTC. They are calculating a delta for small amount of time.

Comment: Just a remark: The login will almost always fail on minute boundaries. hh:mm:59:99*.

Comment: They don't have you pass the time offset as a separate parameter so they can validate the key?  Yikes!  They should also return a specific error for when your time is too far off from their server time, with the delta,